# Errors in Transposing and Performing Dot Product on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to transpose a DataFrame and then calculate the dot product of the DataFrame with its transpose. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
})

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

df_transposed = df.transpose

print(df_transposed)

df_product = df.dot(df_transposed)

print(df_product)
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'dot' with these indexers [0] of type 'int'
```

Comment: `df_transposed = df.transpose` ... shouldn't that be `df_transposed = df.transpose()`?

Comment: Btw, the provided code throws a different error: IndexError: tuple index out of range.

Comment: Can you post your result of print(df_transposed) ?

Comment: It appears to work after  the @BigBen fix to df.transpose(). https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben